# Zip contains a folder of archives, how to get the comments of each zip in the archive using Python?

Tags: python, zip

I have a ZIP file which contains a folder with a lot of zip files (I am not sure if those are zip files because they end with .(Number) such as .100 , .812 etc..)
that contain a comment, how do I get each comment with python?

I've tried using this code:

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(r'D:\XXX\Desktop\MyZip\archives', 'r') 
for i in range (20):
   print(archive.getinfo("unzipme."+str(i)).comment)
```

As you can see, the "big" zip file is MyZip, and the folder in it is "archives"

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/XXX/PycharmProjects/helper/help1.py", line 2, in <module>
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(r'D:\XXX\Desktop\MyZip\archives', 'r')
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\zipfile.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\XXX\\Desktop\\MyZip\\archives'
```

But it does not work... any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly is an "unzipped zip file that contains a comment"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I'll edit

Comment: You're getting an error, right?  Will you share it?

Comment: @DanFarrell hey, I've edited :) thanks!

Comment: Is the path correct? You should be targeting a zipfile.. I don't see a `.zip` file.

Comment: @TrooperZ Hey, the path is ok, I need to get in the "archives" folder, the myZip is a zip file, and "archives" is a folder in it, when I add a .zip after MyZip (now: MyZip.zip) it gets the same error :(

Comment: Try doing `open("The zipfile's directory")`. See if it returns a error.

Comment: before the loop? just this command? only open? :)

Comment: @TrooperZ Hey, please watch my edit, I have a zip file that contain a folder that contain a lot of files with the ending of a number such as .100 , .121 , .700 etc

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to access the contents of a nested zip file? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930515/unzip-nested-zip-files-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to traverse the directory and check all zip files separately to get the comment of every single archive:

```
import zipfile, os
for file in os.listdir("/home/user/archives"):
    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') 
        print "%s: %s" % (file,archive.comment,)
```

which will output

```
SevSeg-3.3.0.zip: 4d6b8654353bfeab69efaf90e8f14c8d37b98101
adafruit-Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library-1.0.0-3-g99381df.zip: 99381df8ba1dd440c85bacaadb13d016158e7bf8
LiquidCrystal_PCF8574-master.zip: 9236b861ae7b68062f71741c91bca5936689c30e
```