# Recursive zip file decompression in python

Tags: python, linux, zip, unzip

I am sorry about my English
it means the a.txt file is compressed into a3000.zip file, and then the a3000.zip file is compressed into a2999.zip file, and so on until the a0.zip file.
I only have a0.zip file, how can I view a.txt file.

Comment: Welcome to `SO`. Your question does not include any code where we could help, please edit your question and provide it.

Comment: Its one outer zip file and then a zip in a zip in a zip...?

Comment: If you know all of the names, this, at least on a unix like system, is `cat a3000.zip | unzip -p a2999.zip | unzip -p a2998.zip | .... | unzip -p a1.zip | unzip -p orignal_file > original_file`. You could write something to generate that string and pass it to `subprocess.call(the_command, shell=True)`.

Comment: I am sorry about my English
it means the a.txt file is compressed into a3000.zip file, and then the a3000.zip file is compressed into a2999.zip file, and so on until the a0.zip file.
I only have a0.zip file, how can I view a.txt file.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930515/unzip-nested-zip-files-in-python

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide any code so, its difficult to help accurately,but i think **regex** might help you
**regex -**https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

```
import re
x='a1.zip->a2.zip->a3.zip'
y=re.search('a3000.zip')
print(open(y))
```

this code might help you

Comment: I am sorry about my English
it means the a.txt file is compressed into a3000.zip file, and then the a3000.zip file is compressed into a2999.zip file, and so on until the a0.zip file.
I only have a0.zip file, how can I view a.txt file.