# How to read .tar.gz file in GCS Bucket by spring boot app in Google Kubernetes engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GCS bucket where I upload .tar.gz files. A notification to the app in Kubernetes Engine is sent by Google PUB-SUB whenever there is a new file upload. App has listener that  listens to the notification and has to read the .tar.gz file.

I have set up topic/subscribesr notification from GCS to the APP. I am unable to determine how to read .tar.gz file when notification comes.

I tried below code to read .tar.gz but its not what I should be doing. It gave non readable characters & i am not unzipping it. I used google-cloud-storage lib.

```
if(map.containsValue("OBJECT_FINALIZE") ){
           Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setProjectId(projectId)
                    .setCredentials(creaCredentialsProvider.getCredentials()).build().getService();


           try(ReadChannel reader = storage.reader(archiveMessage.getBucket(), archiveMessage.getName())){
               ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(64 * 1024);
               while (reader.read(bytes) > 0) {
                   bytes.flip();
                   System.out.println((char)bytes.get());
                   bytes.clear();
               }

           }


        }
```

I looked at persistent disks & transcoding which doesn't look straight forward.
Any help with direction I should be going or code samples are really appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned that you looked at transcoding; did you attempt to enable Decompressive transcoding? GCS supports Decompressive transcoding which allows gzip-compressed objects on Cloud Storage to be served as the file itself to the requester, without compression. This seems to me like what you are attempting to achieve. According to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#decompressive_transcoding), the object must meet 2 criteria:

[1] The file is gzip-compressed when stored in Cloud Storage.
[2]The associated metadata includes Content-Encoding: gzip.

Comment: So here I have two levels of compression. One is TAR where actual files are compressed & then GZIP which compresses the tar. So if I enable transcoding , I would be able to read TAR. But Is there a way to read files within TAR without downloading the file to disk?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no feature available with Transcoding in the Google Cloud Platform that can offer the two-level decompression, especially with the tar.gz file. However, following the response provided in this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293809/how-to-walk-a-tar-gz-file-that-contains-zip-files-without-extraction#answer-3294052), it seems there is a programmatic way to workaround this issue. You would use the tarfile.TarFile.extractfile method to by-pass having to extracting to disk.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature available with Transcoding in the Google Cloud Platform that can offer the two-level decompression, especially with the tar.gz file. However, following the response provided in this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293809/how-to-walk-a-tar-gz-file-that-contains-zip-files-without-extraction#answer-3294052), it seems there is a programmatic way to workaround this issue. You would use the tarfile.TarFile.extractfile method to by-pass having to extracting to disk